# Differentiability of a supremum of a family of functions with respect to a parameter

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $f : \Bbb R \times M \to [0, \infty)$ be smooth, with $M$ a compact smooth manifold. Let $g : \Bbb R \to [0, \infty)$ be given by $g(t) = \sup _{x \in M} f(t,x)$. Is it true that $g$ is smooth? The issue here is the permutation of $\lim$ and $\sup$ - what techniques should I apply?

Uniform convergence is out of the question. If instead of $\sup$ I had had an integral, I would have tried to use the dominated convergence theorem, or any other result from this family of theorems, but what to try here? Since $\sup$ is not additive, I cannot view it as a positive linear functional, therefore I cannot use the Riesz-Markov representation theorem on it (which would have given me a positive measure to which the dominated convergence theorem would have applied).

Answer (score 3):

Define $M=(-1,1)$ and
$$
f(t,x) = xt
$$
Then
$$
g(t) = \sup_{x\in M} (xt) = |t|,
$$
which is non-smooth.

---

It can be shown that $g$ is continuous: Take a sequence $(t_n)$ with $t_n\to  t$. Then for each $n$ there is $x_n$ with $g(t_n)=f(t_n,x_n)$
and $f(t_n,x_n) \ge f(t_n, y)$ for all $Y\in M$.
Since $M$ is compact, $x_{n_k}\to x$ for some subsequence. Then passing to the limit in the inequality gives $f(t,x)\ge f(t,y)$ for all $y\in M$,
hence $g(t)=f(t,x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(t_n,x_{n_k})=\lim_{k\to\infty}g(t_{n_k})$.
The value $g(t)$ does not depend on the chosen subsequence and limit point $x$, hence the whole sequence $g(t_n)$ converges, and $g$ is continuous at $t$.

Comment: Good answer! I wonder whether replacing $\Bbb R$ with $[0, \infty)$ for the domain of $t$ changes things. This renders your example moot - can you come up with another one in this new situation? (I have changed the endpoints of $M$ to make it without boundary (as I intended my $M$ to be).)

Comment: @AlexM. just make a translation: $f(t,x)=x(t-1)$, then $g$ is non-differentiable at $t=1$.

Comment: Indeed, one gets $g(t) = |t-1|$. It seems that there is no hope for smoothness, but in your examples $g$ is at least continuous (so I may still consider its derivatives as Schwartz distributions). Is $g$ continuous in general?

Comment: Something is strange regarding continuity: taking $f(t,x) = 1 - |x|^t$ with $x \in [-1,1]$ and $t \in [0,\infty)$, we get that $g(0) = 0$ while $g(t) = 1$. Besides, shouldn't the inequality be $f(t_n,x_n) \ge f(t_n, y)$, given that $x_n$ is a point where the $\sup$ is attained? And where do you use this inequality in proving that $g(t) = \lim _k g(t_{n_k})$?

Comment: My example given above is mistaken: the function $(t,x) \mapsto 1 - |x|^t$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$. To see this, approach $(0,0)$ by the points $(\frac 1 n, 0)$ to obtain $1$, and then by the points $(\frac 1 n, \frac 1 n)$ to obtain $0$. (I never seem to learn to check even the statements that seem trivial and common sense.)

Comment: Your reasoning about continuity shows this: if $t_n \to t$ then there exists a subsequence $t_{n_k} \to t$ such that $g(t) = \lim g(t_{n_k})$, which is not enough to prove continuity. You realize this so you end your argument with the sentence about the independence of $g(t)$ of the subsequence. I am afraid that I don't understand this.

Comment: The supremum of a function is uniquely determined and independent of how one approimates it - this is behind the argument. Any limit point of $(x_k)$ realizes the supremum, this supremum is unique (the limit points not)